# How to remove properties from object to cast it to another type with identical properties

Tags: typescript

I want to transform one object of a specific type of another object where the first objects properties contains all properties of the other but has some additional.

Given the following example:

```
type person = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
    id: number;
}

type personWithoutId = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
}

const person: person = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 30,
    address: '123 Main St',
    id: 1
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const { id, ...rest } = person;

const alex: personWithoutId = rest;
```

This works great, however eslint is complaining and I want to get rid of the rule disabling comment.
I can not `delete` the property since it is not optional.

So what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use classes to this as they works like types:

```
class Person {
  name = ''
}

class PersonWithId extends Person {
  id = ''
  // add here other propeties you want
}
```

Then you can create an object cleaner function like this:

```
function clearObject<T>(C: any, o: any, f: any = {} ): T {
  Object.keys( C ).forEach( ( key: any ) => {

      const keyType = typeof C[ key ]
      const Value = o[ key ] ?? C[ key ] 

      if (
        !!Value &&
        keyType === 'object' &&
        Object.keys( Value ).length > 0
      ) {
        // if key is another object
        if ( !Array.isArray( Value ) ) {
          f[ key ] = clearObject( C[ key ], Value )
          return f
        }

        // if key is an array
        Value.forEach( ( itens: any ) => {
          f[ key ] = clearObject( C[ key ], itens, f[ key ] )
          return f
        } )
      }
      
      // assign the value to it's key
      f[ key ] = Value
    } )
    // return the new object cleared and typed
    return f as T
}
```

This function will loop for each key of the type class and get from the object only keys that exists in your type class, then creates a new object and return it typed.
You can use it like this:

```
const person: PersonWithId = {
  name: 'John',
  id: 1
}

const cleared = clearObject<Person>(new Person(), person)
```

Note that now `cleared` variable is from type Person and if you try to get Id from it TS will show you an error.

This works for any Object you want to clear based on another type class without any TS error

[Here's a code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-clear-object-pw5gn7)

Comment: nice, it works, but I was hoping for a simpler solution tbh ;)

Comment: you can simplify the object cleaner function like in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/ts-clear-object-simplified-iv056l?file=/demo.tsx) updated version.
But this will not loop in nested objects or arrays, it'll only remove keys those aren't on new type

Comment: thanks, one stupid question, why do you have `f` as a parameter with default value instead of just having it declared inside the function

Comment: it's not a stupid question, you can use it in parameters or declared inside function body... in the answer I've used as param, in simplified I've used declared, both ways works but as parameter is a little more lazy ( you doesn't need to type 'const' word XD )

Comment: as parameter is usefull when you want to assign a default value to the variable, e.g: `function sum(x: number, y:number = 10)` if you call `sum(5)` the result gonna be 15 because `y` doesn't have any override value so JS uses the default `10` value

Answer (score 1):

a) mark the var as unused (`no-unused-vars` is generally configured to ignore `/^_/`)

```
const { id: _id, ...rest } = person;
const alex: personWithoutId = rest;
```

b) make it a function to eslint-ignore only in one place

```
function omitId<T extends { id: any }>(o: T): Omit<T, 'id'> {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const { id, ...rest } = o;
    return rest;
}
const alex: personWithoutId = omitId(person);
```

Comment: well I tried to ignore it in the eslint rule like this: `"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "^_", "varsIgnorePattern": "^_" }],`
but that did not help